# Angular: Components do not get updated with data from public service variable

Tags: angular

Since there are not a lot of `Source` items in this app, I thought I'd be clever and design a service that also acts as a repository, and update internally whenever the service adds, updates or removes an item.

In order to populate the repository on the first use, my main component then runs `listSources()` once by subscribing to it. All other components get the service injected and in their templates I use `let source of sourceService.sources` to get the sources.

However, when I alter the sources through `addSource()` or any other means, these changes are not reflected in my other components. I also tried using a subject, but that got even more confusing and didn't work for me either.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is the service:

```
export class SourceService { // truncated for brevity
  public sources: Source[] = [];

  constructor( ) { } 

  public listSources(): Observable<Source[]> {
    // if sources are already loaded, just return from memory
    if (this.sources.length > 0) {
      return of(this.sources);
    }

    return this.http.get<Source[]>(sourceUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(sources => {
        sources.forEach((source, index, sources) => {
          this.sources.push(source);
        });
        });
  }

  public addSource(source: Source): Observable<Source> {
    return this.http.post<Source>(sourceUrl, source, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(data => {
        // update memory
        this.sources.push(Object.assign(new Source(), Source.EMPTY_MODEL));
      })
    );
  }
```

elsewhere, a component which has `sourceService` injected, has the following template:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let source of sourceService.sources" [value]="source.id">{{ source.title }}</mat-option>
```

Comment: can u show us where you are injecting the service?

Comment: absolutely; I'm passing it to the constructor and the providers section in my app.module file

Comment: so far didn't find any issue with your approach. If possible could you please create plunkr

Comment: indeed. I was doing everything correctly but was calling the wrong function. Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export class SourceService { // truncated for brevity
  public sources: Source[] = [];
  public sources$ = new BehavoiurSubject<Source[]>([]);
  constructor( ) { } 

  public listSources(): Observable<Source[]> {
    // if sources are already loaded, just return from memory
    if (this.sources.length) {
      this.sources$.next(this.sources);
      return of(this.sources);
    }

    return this.http.get<Source[]>(sourceUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(sources => {
        sources.forEach((source, index, sources) => {
          this.sources.push(source);
        });
        this.sources$.next(this.sources);
        });
  }

  public addSource(source: Source): Observable<Source> {
    return this.http.post<Source>(sourceUrl, source, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(data => {
        // update memory
        this.sources.push(Object.assign(new Source(), Source.EMPTY_MODEL));
        this.sources$.next(this.sources);
      })
    );
  }
```

And in your component

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="sourceService.sources$ | async as sources>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let source of sources" [value]="source.id">{{ source.title }}</mat-option> 
    </ng-container >
```

Comment: Thanks Sai. I just figured out my problem and it's just complete stupidity: I was calling a different function than I thought I was. But your solution intrigues me. I've seen the use of Subjects but I don't really understand the difference in this case.

Comment: Your original solution should work. since you did not provide a plunker, I wasn't sure about the data flow from the service to the component. Using subjects will always ensure the data in the component is up to date